# What is difference between .sendText() and System.out.println in websockets api

Tags: java, html, websocket

I'm beginner of java HTML5 websockets api.

I came across the following,Can any one please tell to me what is difference between

`session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello");`

and

```
System.out.println(hello);
```

code is:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("Connected to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Difference in which aspect ?

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("hello");` only writes strings to the console, that is, if you are running this on a Windows Environment for example, that will cause a console window to pop up with the word "Hello". This is usually used for debugging purposes.


`sendText` is used to send a string to the client, that is, someone connected to your app like a remote computer or a web browser.


`sendText` is what you should use. `System.out.println` is worthless to the browser. Anything you print with `System.out.println` will not leave your server and will not be received by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

sendText() should push the supplied text through the websocket to browsers listening on that socket.  System.out.println() is just going to print data out to your server's stdout (the data will not be pushed to listeners).

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(...) prints to the local console context only. If there is no local console you'll see no output.

session.getBasicRemote().sendText(...); prints to a remote connection.

They both perform a print of text, but to two entirely different targets.